# Android emulator not starting on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: android, eclipse

I get an error that I can not fix by my self when lauching the Android emulator in Eclipse.

- Eclipse v3.6 or v3.7
- Android ADT 12
- SDK R12
- Ubuntu 10.10 64bit

When launching the HelloWorld app I get the following printout:

```
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Crazy ------------------------------
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Crazy] Android Launch!
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Crazy] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Crazy] Performing com.crazy.CrazyActivity activity launch
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Crazy] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Crazy] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-07-30 16:08:55 - Emulator] Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 583: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

Anyone having any clue about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, upgrading the ia32-libs package on my debian box fixed the same problem for me.